# NSAttributedString & decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping ranges

Tags: ios, cocoa, unicode, nsstring, nsattributedstring

I'm running into problems with international (in this case Korean) `NSString` values.

The same input string is used in two different parts of the program. The first part finds a substring that needs highlighting, stores the `NSString` and the range for the highlighting into a database.

The second part of the program retrieves the string and displays the highlighting.

The marking part is done using an `NSString` that has been normalized in Unicode Normalization Form C using the `precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping` method on `NSString`. An `NSRange` and an `NSString` are then stored into the Core Data database.

The graphical highlighting is performed by retrieving the `NSRange` and `NSString` from the database, putting the `NSString` into the same Form C using the same method, using this to initialize an `NSMutableAttributedString` and using the `NSRange` to set its text attributes.

At this stage, the program crashes because the `NSMutableAttributedString` is 80 characters long, whereas the `NSString` was 81 characters long..

`NSAttributedString` does not have a `precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping` method and I assume it changes the representation internally resulting in a different encoding and thus length.

What can I do?

- is the a way of forcing `NSAttributedString` to keep an underlying encoding?
- is there a way of converting an `NSRange` from one encoding to another?

or is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

I did eventually find out what had happened. In one particular place in the program I mistakenly used `decomposed`​String​With​Canonical​Mapping rather than `precomposed​String​With​Canonical​Mapping` and that's where the "wrong" mapping came from.